# How can I handle error when I use Entity Framework Core to athorize user but MySql server is unavailable?

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, entity-framework-core, database-connection

I am using Entity Framework Core with Identity to authorize users in a Minimal API project and I want to response some error code with message when app can not connect with database (for example database is not turned on).

For example I have this endpoint:

```
app.MapGet("/identity/deleteuser", async (HttpContext context) => {...}).RequireAuthorization("user-policy");
```

and when I will try to use it when database is down I want to send response with 500 Internal Server Error message to client.

There are my current `AddDbContext` and `AddIdentity` configurations:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseMySql(identityDbConnString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(identityDbConnString), opt => { opt.EnableRetryOnFailure(); }) ;
            });
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUserExtended, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

I want to response some error code with message when app can not connect with database when app is trying to authorize user for endpoint.